# Simple API but Endless Capture from Fiddler -- hammered with 201

Tags: c#, rest, api, get, fiddler

I am running a simple API with Get, but I get constant, unlimited stream from Fiddler, now reaching into the thousands, after I launch the app through the "Run on Google Chrome" button (see first column of screenshot below):
[image: FIDDLER]

Getting hammered with result 201.

The code below works as expected.
This is my call (defaults to Get):
http://localhost:50015/api/Values
My result is correct; it returns a list of strings in browser.

This makes it impossible to follow the tutorial.

Its an awesome tutorial...but I am stuck on this step.
I am sharing the link to that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbKBcDX8DDQ&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=3

This is my code from the Values controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        static List<string> strings = new List<String>()
        {
            "value0","value1","value2"
        };


        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return strings; ;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return strings[id];

        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            strings.Add(value);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            strings[id] = value;
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            strings.RemoveAt(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A wonder if it is possible to block code 201 result?

Answer (score 0):

In Taskbar go to IIS Express

[image: IIS EXpress in taskbar]

Right click on it and stop your site.

[image: Stop Site]

Comment: no, the website has to be up, and I shouldn't be hammered.  else I can't follow the video....

Answer (score 0):

I have both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installed in my computer.
I used visual Studio 2015 because I wanted to follow along the demo that was cone in Visual Studio 2015.  But that's the one that has the problem.  when I open up the same project in 2017, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler by default capture all processes. That's why we are seeing endless capture from Fiddler. However, we are interested only in intercepting our local requests. 
This can be done by clicking on **All Processes** at the bottom left corner and selecting **Hide All**.
The local request URL can be put directly using the Composer tab and that can be used to test the API.